# AWS CloudFormation - How to upload some python/flask code

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, flask, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cloudformation

I have writen a python/flask code which I succesfully uploaded to an EBS (elastic beanstalk) enviroment and everything works fine.  I have also written a yaml script creating a cloudformation (CF) stack which succesfully launches a custom VPC/subnets/security group/application load balancer with target group and autoscaling group with EC2 instances. Now, I would  like to upload my Python/Flask code in the above CF stack so it works exactly like the EBS application.

Would you please point me in the right direction?

Thank you in advance.

PS. I have not included the CF template since it is over 300 lines long. I dont need anybody to actually solve the problem for me. Just a nudge it the correct direction.

Answer (score 0):

See [AWS::Lambda::Function.Code](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-lambda-function.html#cfn-lambda-function-code) and [Code Definitions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-lambda-function-code.html)

You can either point it @ a zip file in S3 or if not too long, embed it in the template (see [ZipFile](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-lambda-function-code.html#cfn-lambda-function-code-zipfile))

Comment: Thank you both Marcin and TIm Basset.Will pursue.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way is to create a CI/CD pipeline using AWS CodePipeline. It integrates natively [with ElasticBeanstalk](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/continuous-deployment-pipeline/) and [even with CloudFormation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/continuous-delivery-codepipeline.html) to allow for automated deployments of new EB application versions and/or CF stacks.